# Form a query string for comparison with the content of a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following formulae in googlesheets

```
=QUERY('Kramerville KH'!$E$5:$V$500,ʺSelect V WHERE E=ʺ&B2&ʺ)
```

It gives an error wanting to put an extra set of inverted commas and bracket at the end, which then obviously gives an error since there is an extra bracket...  Anyone know what the issue is with this formulae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If B2 is foo, you want the second argument to be

Select V WHERE E='foo'

(Use single quotes for strings within a query string). So, it should be

```
ʺSelect V WHERE E='ʺ & B2 & "'"
```

(with spaces for readability)